# Name of this effect, or related plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What do you call this kind of effect, that Tumbler has, where content are displayed and animated?

http://www.tumblr.com/

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 `div`'s here,

`1st div - till the copyright statement` and

`2nd div - 30 reasons you'll love Tumblr`

When you hit the `down arrow`, `div1` slides up, the jQuery code will look something like this

```
$("#div1").slideUp(1000);
```

this `slidUp` will allow another div, `div3 - The easiest way to blog` to appear.

and the same is done when you hit the `home button`,

The `div3` slides down, the jQuery code will look something like  this,

```
$("#div3").slideDown1(1000);
```

this `slideDown` will let `div1` appear again.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What would you call this? I wouldn't call it a slider.

Comment: well, you're actually playing around with multiple div's here, some are hidden, so you have to use native jQuery `slideUp | slideDown` and `fadeIn | fadeOut` to replicate the "tumblr" effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally called a slider.

Comment: I wouldn't call it that my self. The first content is fixed height, and the next content is a "normal" page. Could you call it anything else?

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing here? I assumed you were referring to the Tumblr homepage where it slides in different images.

Comment: I almost made this a comment, would you care to expand your answer?

Comment: I'm talking about the expanding and collapsing effect, that are shown when you click "30 reasons why you will love Tumbler"...

Comment: Read the OP's question, it's an answer.